# UnicodeEncodeError when parsing month name with Python strptime

Tags: python, datetime, unicode, locale

I have to parse a German date in MONTH YEAR format where MONTH is the full name of the month. I set the appropriate locale in Python and then try to parse the date with `strptime`. For example:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "deu_deu") # Locale name on Windows
datetime.strptime(dt, "%B %Y")
```

On encountering a month with a non-ASCII character in its name I get a `UnicodeEncodeError`. The date is being pulled from an XML file delivered via a web service. Is there a way I can transform my date string to that it works with `strptime`?

Comment: Try using `dt.decode('utf-8')` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code solves the problem.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "deu_deu") # Locale name on Windows
datetime.strptime(dt.encode("iso-8859-16"), "%B %Y")
```

Answer (score 3):

No answer, just a test (on Unix, though):

```
>>> import locale, datetime
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "de_de")
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("März 2012", "%B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

The above works as expected. Now simulate unicode as input - März contains a [LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/E4/index.htm):

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime("M\u00E4rz 2012", "%B %Y"))
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' ...
```

The same can be *achieved* with the built-in unicode function:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(unicode("März 2012", "utf-8"), "%B %Y")
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' ....
```

Now try with appropriate encoding:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(u"M\u00E4rz 2012".encode('utf-8'), "%B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

Again, this is not on Windows - so not really an answer, but it may contain a hint.

---

Just to investigate a bit more - a scenario, where one deals with an data external source (using JSON for this example, YMMV for XML):

I think a proper JSON encoder will give you unicode, and [RFC4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) seems to hint to that:

> Any character may be escaped.  If the character is in the Basic
>      Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be
>      represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed
>      by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that
>      encode the character's code point.  The hexadecimal letters A though
>      F can be upper or lowercase.

So to simulate that with python (nobody would parse JSON that way, this is just a simulation):

```
>>> import json
>>> s = json.dumps({"date" : "März 2012"}).split(":")[1].replace(
        '"', "").replace("}", "").strip().decode("unicode_escape")
>>> # and sure enough ...
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%B %Y")
...
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4 ...

>>> # and again, with the right encoding ...
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(s.encode("utf-8"), "%B %Y")
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks miku. I played around with it some more and was able to succeed by using `datetime.strptime(dt.encode("iso-8859-16"))`, where ISO-8859-16 is the standard character set for Germany. It looked like the string was already UTF-8 encoded, but for whatever reason I was unable to get strptime to process it, at least on Windows.

Comment: Great. Maybe you can write a one (or two)-line answer to your own question and then mark it as *accepted* (48h later), so this question doesn't stay in the "unanswered" category.