# How to use russian date string with strptime

Tags: python, encoding

I parse html with python and there is date string: `[ 24-Янв-17 07:24 ]`. "Янв" is "Jan". I want to convert it into datetime object.

```
# Some beautifulsoup parsing
timeData = data.find('div', {'id' : 'time'}).text

import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeData, u'[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]')
```

The error is:

> ValueError: time data '[ 24-\xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb2-17 07:24 ]' does
>   not match format '[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]'

`type(timeData)` returns unicode. Encoding `timeData` from `utf-8` returns `UnicodeEncodeError`. What's wrong?

---

chardet returns `{'confidence': 0.87625, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}` and when I write: `datetime.datetime.strptime(timeData.encode('utf-8'), ...)` it returns error as above.

---

Original page has `window-1251` encoding.

```
print type(timeData)
print timeData


timeData = timeData.encode('cp1251')
print type(timeData)
print timeData
```

returns

```
<type 'unicode'>
[ 24-Янв-17 07:24 ]
<type 'str'>
[ 24-???-17 07:24 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError when parsing month name with Python strptime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235274/unicodeencodeerror-when-parsing-month-name-with-python-strptime)

Comment: Or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2571515/2877364)

Comment: @cxw No, it didn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I strftime a date object in a different locale?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593661/how-do-i-strftime-a-date-object-in-a-different-locale)

Comment: Maybe this helps?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235274/unicodeencodeerror-when-parsing-month-name-with-python-strptime

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Quick fix

Got it!  `янв` has to be *lower-case* in CPython 2.7.12.  Code (works in CPy 2.7.12 and CPy 3.4.5 on cygwin):

```
# coding=utf8
#timeData='[ 24-Янв-17 07:24 ]'
timeData='[ 24-янв-17 07:24 ]'    ### lower-case
import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeData, u'[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]')
print(result)
```

result:

```
2017-01-24 07:24:00
```

If I use the upper-case `Янв`, it works in Py 3, but in Py 2 it gives

```
ValueError: time data '[ 24-\xd0\xaf\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb2-17 07:24 ]' does not match format '[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]'
```

### General case

To handle this in general **in Python 2**, lower-case first (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9943237/2877364)):

```
# coding=utf8
timeData=u'[ 24-Янв-17 07:24 ]'
       # ^ unicode data
import datetime
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
print(timeData.lower())     # works OK
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    timeData.lower().encode('utf8'), u'[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]')
    ##               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ back to a string
    ##       ^^^^^^^ lowercase
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[ 24-янв-17 07:24 ]
2017-01-24 07:24:00
```

I can't test it with your beautifulsoup code, but, in general, get Unicode
data and then use the above.

Or, if at all possible, switch to Python 3 :) .

### Explanation

So how did I figure this out?  I went looking in the CPython source for the code to `strptime` ([search](https://github.com/python/cpython/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=strptime)).  I found the handy [`_strptime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_strptime.py) module, containing [`class LocaleTime`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_strptime.py#L31).  I also found a [mention](http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/15560/_strptime.LocaleTime) of `LocaleTime`.  To print the available month names, do this (added on to the end of the code under "Quick fix," above):

```
from _strptime import LocaleTime
lt = LocaleTime()
print(lt.a_month)
```

`a_month` has the abbreviated month names per [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Lib/_strptime.py#L39).

On Py3, that yields:

```
['', 'янв', 'фев', 'мар', 'апр', 'май', 'июн', 'июл', 'авг', 'сен', 'окт', 'ноя', 'дек']
      ^ lowercase!
```

On Py2, that yields:

```
['', '\xd1\x8f\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb2',
```

and a bunch more.  Note that the first character is `\xd1\x8f`, and in your error message, `\xd0\xaf` doesn't match.

Comment: @Ockonal Glad to be able to help!  I learned some new things, which I always enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can just change russian month name with english:

```
ru_to_eng_months = {'Янв': 'Jan', } # fill it with other months

def ru_to_eng_datetime(ru) -> string:
    s = ru.split('-')
    eng_month  = ru_to_eng_months[s[1]]
    return s[0] + '-' + eng_month + '-' + s[2]

s = u'[ 24-Янв-17 07:24 ]'
dateTime = ru_to_eng_datetime(s)
result = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateTime, u'[ %d-%b-%y  %H:%M ]')
print(result) # 2017-01-24 07:24:00
```

Comment: Hey, even better yet, why not just use `datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 24)`